# How to load a local image in JavaFX WebView component

Tags: javascript, javafx-2, javafx

I have a set of BufferedImage objects I want to load into my JavaFX WebView (as images that I can paint to the canvas). It's easy to load HTML and  execute JS whenever you need to, but I'm wondering what the best way of getting a BufferedImage into a HTMLImage is. Would you recommend :

1) Saving the file as a .jpg and using the file:// prefix

2) Some other way to load the image info the web engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 Saving the file as a .jpg and using the file:// prefix

This is likely going to be easiest.

When in doubt, I'd always recommend the easiest solution :-)

> 2 Some other way to load the image info the web engine.

This is likely to be harder.

One possibility is to define your own protocol handler such as outlined in a [New Era for Java Protocol Handlers](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/dm_protocolHandlers/java_protocol.pdf).  Then you can use your custom protocol to fetch the image bits to the WebView.  This process, if done right will, will eliminate the need for disk I/O.

Comment: I ended up saving as a jpg. I was worried it would slow the system down but it ended up being no problem. Thanks for your help!